# Is this question sufficiently improved to be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm interested in reviving my question [Meaning of phrase "Early/late in the piece"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304316/meaning-of-phrase-early-late-in-the-piece). It was closed and then automatically deleted. I've tried to edit it to improve it. Is this question any good now, or is it still lacking something?

(After it got put "on hold" I tried to improve it, but I wasn't sure at that point what procedure I was supposed to follow to possibly get its "on hold" status reviewed.)

Comment: What I struggle with, on this question, is that personally, I've not encountered "*<early/late> in the piece*" generically. It may be an Australian idiom. It might help the question if you could find a few quotes from credible sources (literature or journalism) which employ the phrase in a generic context. Having said that, my bet is you're chasing ghosts: from your description, the analogous American idiom is "*<early/late> in the **game***", and specifically *because* it's a generic, fixed, idiom, it's pointless to ask *which* game is being discussed. It's abstract. There is no game.

Comment: Having said that, it's possible someone could track down the etymology to identify which sense of *piece* was originally intended, even if the meaning has become bleached out and abstracted away since it was coined. I'd speculate that originally, the American idiom "*... in the game*" originally referred to baseball (what more American game?), and similarly "*...in the piece*" was inspired by the musical sense. But that's conjecture; I haven't (and likely won't) do the legwork to confirm or deny those suspicions. (And it's worth asking yourself: ultimately, *does it matter*?).

Comment: You said you found a few examples using Google search; I'd like to see the question edited to include one or two of these.

Comment: ... So I edited it now to add two. Of course, you can remove them if you don't like them or replace them with others you fell are better examples.

Comment: Those examples are great. Funny that the first one comes from a forum post asking a similar question as I am.

Comment: Did you look up 'piece' in the OED to see if there are any entries on 'piece' that define it something close to 'a sequence of events' for which there are early and late events? Add that to your question.

Comment: I don't subscribe to OED, but I'll have a look at another dictionary.

Comment: I have no idea why the original question was deleted or put on hold, but I found the question, as it exists today, reasonable. And thus submitted an answer.

Comment: @CorvusB Looks like it was because there were no examples or context. You can click on the question's revision history at the bottom where it says when it was last edited to see the original version. That's not the best answer I've ever seen, but I thought it worth an upvote.

Comment: @DCShannon. I concur that it was not the best of answers. I edited it today, hopefully to make the thoughts clearer and stick more closely to the question. Found the revision history, also. Thanks!

Comment: This question has been put "on hold" again. I'm not sure how to make it clearer though.

Comment: In the comments under the original question, I have protested the 2nd hold, as I entirely concur with @CraigMcQueen. The question is clear enough to provide answers, and I believe the intent of the question is clear. It would be more helpful to add comments asking for specific clarification at this point, rather than the generic "Put on hold - go look up the standards". Frankly, that message is simply not helpful.